# JMeter: HTTP Cookie Manager superseded

Tags: jmeter

I have a series of this warning filling the Log Viewer:

`2024-02-16 10:28:25,232 WARN o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Existing CookieManager HTTP Cookie Manager superseded by HTTP Cookie Manager`

I checked my code and there is only 1 Cookie Manager but still getting this warning.  If I disable this Cookie Manager, it goes away.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs when you have > 1 iteration in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)

If the warning is bothering you or makes [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file analysis harder you can just disable it. In order to do it you need to suppress messages of WARN level for [HTTPSamplerBase](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html) class. It can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase" level="info" additivity="false"/>
```

More information: [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging)